# Global.asax Application_Error doesn't work with Integrated Mode

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, global-asax, integrated-pipeline-mode

Application_Error doesn't work with Integrated Mode but does work with Class Mode.
I would to transfer request to error page using both Integrated Mode and Class Mode. Can this be done or I have to use HTTP module in order to support both modes?

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context != null && Context.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
    {
        Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/reganschroder/archive/2008/07/25/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-application-start.aspx

Comment: ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx

Comment: You can write HTTP module that will handle error. Similar to this one: http://msmvps.com/blogs/vcsjones/archive/2008/12/26/managing-iis-pipeline-mode-for-backward-compatibility.aspx

Comment: If your question was answered, please mark the relevant as the answer. Or provide some feedback so we know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should use HttpContext.Current (HttpContext is a static class). So where you're now using Context, change that to HttpContext.Current

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your code from `Server.Transfer` to `Server.TransferRequest`.
See my answer on another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774502/server-transfer-with-app-pool-set-to-integrated/7472887#7472887).

Comment: I don't believe that the Application_Error event will even fire in Integrated mode... am I wrong?