# server.transfer with app pool set to "integrated"

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, web-config, application-pool

I have a Facebook application and for various reasons, I need it to run with the app pool set to "integrated".  However, when I change the app pool to "integrated", Server.Transfer does not seem to work anymore (It works fine in "classic" mode).  The error is:

No http handler was found for request type 'POST'

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? Where is Server.Transfer getting called from (an HttpModule, a Page_Load, etc)? ASP.NET 4.0 or 2.0?

Comment: It is 4.0 and IIS 7.0 and I am calling it from a Page_Load. It seems pretty straightforward and easy and works fine when the app pool is set to classic.

Comment: Are you trying to transfer within the same domain? If not then you might want to try using Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your code from `Server.Transfer` to `Server.TransferRequest`.

I was getting the same error when running my app on IIS7 in Integrated Mode.
 "No http handler was found for request type 'GET'"  This simple change fixed my problem.